# Embed editable google sheet in React with iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, iframe, content-security-policy

I've been trying to embed a google sheet in my project. The steps looks pretty straightforward.
Following the steps from this [link](https://www.localwebstrategies.com/post/how-to-embed-editable-google-sheets-in-website).
I got the iframe from the sheet publish menu.

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/<docId>/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>`

Then picked the edit url from sheet sharing menu
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<documentId>/edit?usp=sharing`

Then to create the final iframe by combining the above.
`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<documentId>/edit?usp=sharing&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>`

This works fine. When i use this iframe in the html for React app.

Issue:
When I checked out the console I see 2 errors:

`Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://docs.google.com".`

and

`Refused to frame 'https://contacts.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://docs.google.com".`

I've given all possible permissions for edit to on the shared sheet but still can't figure out how to get around these console errors. These errors make the embedded sheet unreliable and unpredictable.

Any help with this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain `unreliable and unpredictable.`

Comment: It is working fine if I don't look at the console. But there're no errors related to security issues or anything else on the UI side apart from console. Due to this, I can't use this in a project as there is no saying when it will stop working or start throwing actual errors to users

Comment: Did you see the errors on the console when loading Google sheets without iframe?

Comment: how can I open the google sheet in my application (react or html page) without an iframe?

Comment: Don't open it in your app. Open it in your browser and see the browser console logs.

Comment: Hey @TheMaster, I tried doing that, but in that case it's opening as a google sheet. and the errors that I'm talking about are anyways specific to framing it in iframe.

Comment: Just want to make sure those errors aren't from Google sheets itself. Google sheets itself has lot of iframes and will throw errors in different browsers. Is the error only specific to iframing the top docs.google.com in react? If not, your concerns are baseless. But Even if it is so, Google sheets can change anyway disallowing iframing, even if there are no errors on the console. So, again, your  concerns about two errors are irrational. Also, note that you're using `/edit` url, which means the sheet must be publicly shared.

Comment: If the top frame `docs.google.com` was refusing to be framed, you wouldn't even see the sheet in your app. It must be one of the nested frames within Google sheets itself.

Comment: I understand what you're saying here. But to use it in a production application I need surety that there are no errors on screen or in console.

Comment: I'm asking why? Even if there are no errors in console, What's the surety that Google won't disallow iframing in the future?

Comment: Ha ha ha. That's a good take on that. But then in that manner nothing is sure. The only point is when we're releasing an application, we can't afford any errors in such form.
And in case google decides to discontinue iframing, there will be a kool off period before its taken off the platform. so that gives everyone around the globe using that to implement alternatives.

Comment: I think you're making a big deal out of those two errors. Regularly, we get many errors in the console in production apps such as Google sheets without any framing. Open  the console and see if there are warnings or errors.